# Spring Boot - Deploy application to Google Cloud App engine but missing app.yaml

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I have a problem which I am trying to solve this problem. I am trying to deploy spring boot application on google cloud app engine, but there is one problem when I try deploy the application I encounter this error below:

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ royAngularProject ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy (default-cli) < package @ royAngularProject <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy (default-cli) @ royAngularProject ---
[INFO] Deleting the staging directory: /home/meodows9992/royAngularProject-spring/target/appengine-staging
[INFO] Staging the application to: /home/meodows9992/royAngularProject-spring/target/appengine-staging
[INFO] Detected App Engine flexible environment application.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.292 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-09T19:39:14+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/140M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy (default-cli) on project royAngularProject: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy failed: java.nio.file
.NoSuchFileException: /home/meodows9992/royAngularProject-spring/src/main/appengine/app.yaml -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
meodows9992@cloudshell:~/royAngularProject-spring (tidy-etching-224411)$
```

May I know what should I do to resolve this issue, sorry I unable to post any codes because I don't know where is the problem located and if I need app.yaml I would like to guide me on how do I install it into my project.

Answer (score 1):

A Standard app.yaml confguration for a maven project developed in java8 should look like this;

```html
runtime: java
env : flex
inbound_services: 
- warmup
derived_file_type:
- java_precompiled

runtime_config: 
  jdk: openjdk8

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
skip_files: app.yaml
```

I believe the documentation of Google Cloud platform needs to be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following location in your project  - src/main/appengine
and place your app.yaml file there.

Since it is a Java application you should mention that to get the app engine standard java environment.

```
runtime: java
```

[image]

Finally Run the below command if you already added the App engine plugin to your POM file.

```
./mvnw -DskipTests appengine:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your pom.xml has `<packaging>war</packaging>` and not `<packaging>jar</packaging>`, if you intend to deploy an appengine-standard application